# how to retrieve value only of JSON by php from database?

Tags: php, json

may I know how to retrieve the value only array in json instead of the whole json object in php from the database?

```
<?php
require_once('dbConnect.php');
$sql = "SELECT RestaurantName FROM Restaurant";
$result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql) or die("Error in Selecting " .       mysqli_error($connection));
$restaurantArray = array();
while($rows = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$restaurantArray[] = $rows;
}
echo json_encode($restaurantArray);
mysqli_close($connection);
?>
```

For example,

```
["Afonso Cláudio", "Água Doce do Norte"]
```

instead of

```
[{"city":"Afonso Cláudio"},{"city":"Água Doce do Norte"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When fetching data from the database as `assoc`, you will get an associative array (which when converted to json will become a json object) as result.
What you are currently doing is adding the row (which is an associative array with one key-value) to your result array. If you *only* want the city, you can easily fetch only that data from the assoc-array.
Changing

```
$restaurantArray[] = $rows;
```

to

```
$resturantArray[] = $rows['city'];
```

should do the trick.

Additionally, if you wanted to reformat the data in the result, and not just push the city name to it, a `array_map` call could be used:

```
$result = array_map(function($assocArr) { 
    return $assocArr['city']; // Or whatever you want the value to be.
}, 
$resturantArray);

echo json_encode($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

How about you change this line:

```
$restaurantArray[] = $rows;
```

With:

```
$restaurantArray[] = $rows['city']; // (or 'RestaurantName')
```